# Is it possible take user text input in a Tkinter dropdown menu? If so, how?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is what I have tried:

```
win = Tk()
menubar = Menu(win)
dropDown = Menu(menubar)
dropDown.add_command(label = "Do something", command = ...)

entry = Entry()
dropDown.add(entry)

menubar.add_cascade(label = "Drop Down", menu = dropDown)
win.config(menu = menubar)
win.update()
```

I have looked through the docs and it seems like there is no way to do it with a single line like `dropDown.add_entry(...)`, but I thought there might be a workaround like using the one of the geometry manager to place the entry in the menu somehow.

I am using Python 3.6 (but I'm not tagging it because I'll get a thousand mods from the Python tag who have no interest in answering my question voting to close for no reason)

Comment: You can do what I do. Create the new menu item and then have a function that removes and then recreates the menu. This way you can add or remove menu items. I have a note taking program that lest me add or remove new sets of notes through the menu.

Comment: I have a menu command called `New` and it links to a function that runs `simpledialog.askstring()`. I take the user input from this `askstring()` to create my variable for a new file name and the function crates the file. You can use this same concept to perform several kinds of task within your GUI including adding new items to your menu. You will need to have another function that updates the menu though.

Comment: @Nae The question specificies "text input"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple program where you can click a menu button to prompt the user for input. Then do something with that input. In this case print to console.

We need to write a function that makes use of `askstring()` from `simpledialog` that you can import from Tkinter. Then take the results of that string the user types and do something with it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("100x50")

def take_user_input_for_something():
    user_input = simpledialog.askstring("Pop up for user input!", "What do you want to ask the user to input here?")
    if user_input != "":
        print(user_input)

menubar = tk.Menu(win)
dropDown = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
dropDown.add_command(label = "Do something", command = take_user_input_for_something)

# this entry field is not really needed her.
# however I noticed you did not define this widget correctly
# so I put this in to give you an example.
my_entry = tk.Entry(win)
my_entry.pack()

menubar.add_cascade(label = "Drop Down", menu = dropDown)
win.config(menu = menubar)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for cluing me in on simpledialog, I didn't know about that. That'll save me a lot of time in the future.

Comment: I bet, if I (or someone) could be bothered, it would be possible to pack one of these dialogs to always appear when a certain menu is clicked, inside that menu. I'm not the best at using the geometry managers though, so maybe not me.

Comment: Well you could use `Toplevel()` to create a custom pop up window when you click the menu button that can be small and a simple entry field. There are work arounds to you needs I am sure `Toplevel()`can help in that matter.

Comment: If I had more detail on exactly what you are trying to do I might be able to give you some viable ideas.

Comment: Your initial answer solved my problem. My program has a "save as" feature and, to take the name input, I could have had the menu call a Toplevel with an Entry and a button in it, but (from past experience) that's a massive pain for something that I might as well just use the input() for, so I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way. Your answer provided that. I only asked the in the way I did because I thought it would be more likely to get answered.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way using the standard menus to have a menu that accepts user input. This is simply not how menus are designed to work.

If you need the user to type in a string, you need to use a dialog.

Comment: That's funny, because Tkinter Menu is, aesthetically at least, the same as old windows dropdowns, and I'm pretty sure they had text entry (for example when selecting a specific font size). Is the similarity purely visual?

Comment: @RegulationHeadgear if I am not mistaken Tkinter uses windows to define the theme of the widgets. But as far as I know Tkinters similarities with old windows menu's is just visual.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: on OSX and Windows, tkinter uses the native menu widgets provided by the platform. They are actual windows or osx menus.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for the clarification. I did not realize they were actual menus from the OS and not just the themes.